# Undefined offset on array but the offset exists

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, offset

I create a Mysql connection array and pass it to a connect method as such:

```
 $database->connect(array(ROOT_DB_HOST, 
        ROOT_DB_NAME, ROOT_DB_USERNAME, ROOT_DB_PASSWORD));
```

When I `print_r()` the array inside the connect method I get what I expect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => localhost
    [1] => dbname
    [2] => dbuser
    [3] => dbpass
)
```

However, inside the connect method I pass the array values to the DSN string and I received and undefined offset on 0,1,2,3. Here is the DSN string:

```
$this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $connection[0] .';dbname=' . $connection[1],     $connection[2], $connection[3]);
```

So I pass the values as an array and plug them into the PDO constructor and receive the errors, I don't know what is going on, any ideas?

Method:

```
public function connect($connection) {
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. $connection[0] .';dbname=' .  $connection[1], $connection[2], $connection[3]);
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in database.class.php on line 16 Notice:
> Undefined offset: 1 in  database.class.php on line 16 Notice:
> Undefined offset: 2 in database.class.php on line 16 Notice: Undefined
> offset: 3 in database.class.php on line 16
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught
> exception 'Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access
> denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in
> database.class.php:20 Stack trace: #0 sandboxx.php(16):
> Database->connect(Array) #1 {main} thrown in database.class.php on
> line 200

Comment: Post the **exact** error message you got.

Comment: Can you also please post the code of the "connect()" method?

Comment: what you get, when you use var_dump array, and var_dump $connection?

Comment: Read exception message stacktrace. It's saying connection to database isn't successful. Hence returned resultset is empty. Hence the error. My 2cc.

Comment: Post the actual code where you build the array and call `connect()`, if what you have at the top is not the exact actual code...

Answer (score -1):

You  have a problem concatenating  your database handle. If you create your
[**dsn**](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) first you then use it in the handler.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$connection[0].';dbname='.$connection[1].'';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $connection[2], $connection[3]);
```

Answer (score -2):

What's the point in storing *constants* in array? Why not to use them already?
Also, you have quite strange way of handling exceptions.

```
public function connect($connection) {
    $opt = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE          =>  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    );
    $dsn = 'mysql:host='. ROOT_DB_HOST .';dbname='.ROOT_DB_NAME; 
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, ROOT_DB_USERNAME, ROOT_DB_PASSWORD, $opt);
}
```

Personally I don't understand why PDO has *such* inconsistent configuration, utilizing three different kinds of settings - DSN, parameters and options.
why can't you just feed PDO with array of settings - it's a mystery.

Comment: I put them in a serialized array and unserialize them because the application has to read/write to multiple remote databases and I just find the code easy to handle that way. As far as my handling of exceptions, I'm always open to learning new ways of doing things so could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I mean `throw new Exception($e->getMessage());` makes no sense.